# Request method 'POST' not supported in Springboot MVC

Tags: spring-boot, post, controller, thymeleaf

Below are my GET and POST methods..
When I run the application, I get this error: Request method 'POST' not supported.

GET Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "userProfiles/{userId}/setup/Tool", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String ToolSetup(Model model, @PathVariable int userId, @RequestParam(value = "update", defaultValue = "false") boolean update) {
    model.addAttribute("formInput", new Resource());

    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);
    if (update) {
        model.addAttribute("update", "update");
    } else model.addAttribute("update", "");
    return "Tool";
}
```

Below is my POST method:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userProfiles/{userId}/setup/Tool", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void makeVideo(@PathVariable Long userId, @ModelAttribute("formInput") Resource formInput,
                                   Authentication authentication,
                                   ModelMap modelMap,
                                   @RequestParam("uploadingFiles") MultipartFile[] uploadingFiles,
                                   @RequestParam("track_value") int trackNumber,
                                   HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException, FrameGrabber.Exception,FrameRecorder.Exception {
    UserProfile userProfile = userProfileRepository.findOne(userId);
    ArrayList<String> photos = new ArrayList<>();
    String audioPath= audioPath1;
    for(MultipartFile file : uploadingFiles){
        photos.add(file.getName());
    }
    formInput.setUploadingFiles(photos);
    modelMap.put("formInput", formInput);

   //some processing with images and the audio
    response.sendRedirect("/userProfiles/" + userId + "/Tool/Processing");   //redirect to notif. page, then redirect to logged in home

}
```

HTML:

```
       <form th:action="@{${#httpServletRequest.requestURI + '?update=true'}}" th:object="${formInput}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I know there are other posts related to this once, and I have tried all the recommended solutions from them but nothing seems to work..
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: press F12 in your browser and capture the exact url. It is a very possible that you are requesting another endpoint.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand..

Comment: What is your browser? Look this  : https://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/Open-Live-Writer/How-to-download-embedded-videos-with-F12_ABD5/image_8.png   You need to detect what is the real http request sent by your web to your api rest. This could be done using **web console** in **network** tab of your browser. I think your web is requesting to wrong http endpoint.